# Add REAL test users to Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I made a test FB page and connected chatbot to it and everything works fine (for me).
It is a simple chatbot that just repeats what you said (work in progress).

Now I'd like to share it with my friends but I can't because app is not published.
Tried to publish it explicitly saying in my app submission that this is only for testing purposes but FB turned it down.

This is just for couple of my friends and this app will change over time as I add better features / bot becomes smarter.

So my question is: is there a way to add real test users like you have on TestFlight for iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Testing should by done before publishing application so that's the most probable reason you gout turned down. To test bot you have to add your friends to bot application (not page) as testers, developers or admins.

To add testers visit **Roles** section on your bot application and click "Add Testers". On following popup enter their Facebook usernames (found on end of their profile URL). For example if your friend is Mark Zuckerberg with following profile link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/zuck
```

you would add him by typing "zuck" in popup. You could also add testers by entering Facebook ID instead of username.

People do not have to be your Facebook friends for you to add them as testers but they will have to accept request and connect to developers hub.

Answer (score 0):

Go the Roles section of your facebook app. You can add testers there, you must be facebook friends I believe.